# Delphi BPL FMX XE3 Form Resource TForm1 not found

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, bpl

I have made a Form which I want to distribute in a BPL.
So I created a new Package and a new Form, added `registerClass` to the initialization section of my form's unit and tried to manually load the BPL file with roughly the following code:

```
var
  frmHost
  : THandle;

  frmClass
  : TPersistentClass;

begin
  frmHost := LoadPackage(PChar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'frm.170.bpl'));
  if frmHost = 0 then //...

  frmClass := GetClass('TForm1');
  if frmClass = nil then // ...

  with TComponentClass(frmClass).Create(nil) as TCustomForm do
  begin
    ShowModal;
    Free;
  end;
end.
```

When I run the application, it stops on line `with TComponentClass(...` and tells me

`Exception-Class EResNotFound with Message 'Resource TForm1 not found'`

What am I missing (except for unloading and cleanup)?

Comment: Try to add to the BPL code: {$E <MyFormFile>.dfm}

Comment: @Alexandr: {$E} is for "executable extension". What will changing the extension from `.bpl` to `.dfm` serve?

Comment: @Ken's reaction here is inexplicable

Comment: @ken It's not a personal attack, it's just a statement of my opinion.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, my mistake. Try {$R <name>.dfm}. may be you foget add DFM to BPL resources. If pas file of yor form in BPL, already contains {$R *.dfm}, try add {$R <name>.dfm} to your exe, that calls the BPL.

Comment: @Alexandr it is a FMX form, so it would be .fmx. Unfortunately, this idea does not work.